# memached out-of-the-box fallback solution

Tags: php, memcached, fallback

I want to use Memached together with native PHP sessions. However, it would be great if there was a simple solution to have the Memcached deamon write the data held in memory to a on-disk database at a fixed interval as a fallback. Are there any solutions for this? I don't want to reinvent the wheel..

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is write a custom session handler that uses memcached but also writes to your database. You can use [session_set_save_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) to do this.